# How to handle my duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Today I asked the question [Use red!50!blue with \definecolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61366/4918) and shortly after asking I found that it’s a duplicate so I voted to close it as duplicate but I wonder what the community prefers?

1. Vote to close the question as duplicate
2. Delete the question

In addition to that, do you think we should answer (own) duplicates with a CW answer to make a short solution fast findable for other users looking at a duplicated question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please vote to close as a duplicate. Only if it's really very similar, such as literally the same, it may be deleted. The reason is, that a duplicate which is different can still lead users to the original solution, if they search with keywords which don't match the original but match the duplicate.

A solution to the duplicate is not necessary. It's splitting the information or creating duplicate solutions. It would be better to improve the solution to the original question, such as making it more generic. The same applies to the question itself.

Comment: Also you can flag for mod attention, to make sure it is closed.